# Not using RequestDispatcher foward and Servlet Annotation

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to access to Servlet class by any link with struct like this: http://localhost:8080/loginjsp/Reading/abc. "abc" can be change,it's up to you.
So that I used Servlet Annotation

> @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/Reading/*").

But the trouble is I can't use RequestDispatcher foward. 
How can i do both of them?

Reading.Java

```
package com.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ReadingTestServlet
 */
@WebServlet(
        urlPatterns = "/Reading/*",
        initParams =
        {
            @WebInitParam(name = "saveDir", value = "D:/FileUpload"),
            @WebInitParam(name = "allowedTypes", value = "jpg,jpeg,gif,png")
        }
)
public class ReadingTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp");    
            rd.forward(request,response); 
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: The `javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:403)` is no error, it is a stack trace line - look higher in the log file, there should be an actual error message. Add it to your question.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? test.jsp is relative to the previous invocation path 'cause you are getting a RequestDispatcher from the request object.

Comment: it has no error, i saw a lot of traces line like this javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:4‌​03) was running.

Comment: Why do you say you can't use forward? What url are you trying to forward to and what error do you get?

Comment: i mean i didn't saw any error on the console box, but it doesn't forward to a jsp page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it and you are right, there is a problem. The problem is that you are into an infinite loop, because your dispatch makes the servlet be called again. The forward urlPattern will match `urlPatterns = "/Reading/*"` (you are using a wildcard). Replace the wildcard '*' with 'abc' in your urlPatterns and will work (I am assuming you put the 'test.jsp' in the /Reading directory)

Btw, consider using

```
getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/absolute/path");
```

in similar situations.

Comment: thank for your comment, but i have to use 'abc' instead of '*', because i want to get URL by getRequestURI() method. 'abc' is the path to my files. Look back to my initParams, After use substring() method, my path look like D:/FileUpload/abc/excel.xsl